# Ring homomorphism and affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, schemes

How to describe all ring homomorphisms $f: A \rightarrow B$, such that
corresponding affine scheme morphism $f: Spec \, B \rightarrow Spec \, A$ is open immersion?

Comment: $\def\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}$Don't we have $f\colon\Spec B \to \Spec A$?

Comment: Of course! I'm sorry. I've edited.

Comment: I asked the same question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20782/ring-theoretic-characterization-of-open-affines

Answer (score 2):

The answers in the link given by Manny are great. Let me just add another sufficient condition which may be simpler to check than, e.g. flatness. 
If

- $A$ is an integrally closed domain,
- $B$ is contained in $\mathrm{Frac}(A)$ and finitely presented over $A$ (as $A$-algebra),
- $f$ is quasi-finite (i.e. for all prime ideals $p$ of $A$, $B/pB$ is artinian),

then $f$ is an open immersion. This is a form of Zariski's Main Theorem.